on websocket ,how can raw::unpack(state_result), or other way to do ? use abieos_bin_to_json?
Problem Description:
When using WebSocket for communication, I need to deserialize the received binary data into a state_result struct, or convert it to JSON format. I understand that I can use fc::raw::unpack for deserialization, or abieos_bin_to_json to convert it to JSON. How can I achieve these operations?
Specific Requirements:
Deserialize state_result Struct:
How can I use fc::raw::unpack to deserialize the received binary data into a state_result struct?
Convert to JSON Format:
How can I use abieos_bin_to_json to convert the received binary data to JSON format?
